# using grep command a .hpp file obtained binary files matched

Tags: c++, shell, unix

In an application, I am trying to see what C++ files or their header files contain/use a specific .hpp file in an include directory, I got all binary files *.o matched. I had included this X.hpp file path with "-I..." when compiled those "a.cpp", "b.cpp" "c.cpp" and "d.cpp" files. If that was the reason, then when I searched another Y.hpp resides in the same included path, it should also show all the binary files (a.o, b.o, c.o and d.o) that I have compiled with the same "-I...", but it was not the case, see below example.  Can anybody tell me what was going on ?

For example -

```
$grep "X.hpp" *.*
Binary file a.o matches
Binary file b.o matches
Binary file c.o matches
Binary file d.o matches

$grep "Y.hpp" *.*
Binary file a.o matches
Binary file b.o matches
Binary file d.o matches
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This is just debug symbol information in the object files, mapping code regions/variable values to source code. This is both to be expected and mandatory for debugging. `strip *.o` can remove these parts of the files. Alternately, you can specify `grep -I` to ignore binary files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this.